# Why does instance of a IWebDriver class throws an exception in Iteration?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I am developing an application using selenium web driver. I am putting a set of task in the 'for' loop. The task is:

- Open a URL using driver object of IWebDriver class.
- Traverse to different different URLs
- At the for loop, I am killing the instance of IWebDriver class with following:
  `driver.Close(); driver.Quit();`

Now when the second iteration starts, the program does not perform the above task, rather it gives an exception.

When I research on the exception, I found the issue is with the `driver.Close(); driver.Quit();`. It's not even closing the browser, but its also removing the instance of a IWebDriver class. How can I handle this situation?

Here is the Sample code:

```
class callingfunction
{
    public static IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Cpath);

    public void function1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
           driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.aaa.org");
           driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.aaa.org/contactus");
           driver.FindElement(By.Name("contact")).SendKeys(contact);
           driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.aaa.org/aboutus");
           //Code logic 

           driver.Close();
           driver.Quit();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `quit()` on the WebDriver *inside* your loop, so on the second iteration you will indeed get errors.

The only place you need it is right at the **very end** of your test. The `close()` call is also unnecessary.

Furthermore, you're not waiting for anything to load, so without [proper waits](http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/webdriver-wait-examples) your `driver.FindElement(By.Name("contact")).SendKeys(contact);` will likely fail often.

Finally you're not doing anything with the 1st or 3rd page requests, so - given the lack of waits - those pages are likely never allowed to fully load.

Comment: the code what I shared above is not complete one. Actually during the iteration, browser open the two tabs and every time when next iteration starts, it opens the another 2 tab. So I want to close the tabs after each iteration because it create an application slow. Can you please suggest what can be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the scenario you are trying to accomplish but I'm hoping that in the process of simplifying the code, you've removed the bits that make this scenario make a little more sense. Having said that...

The problem is that you are closing and quitting the browser driver inside the `for` loop but never instantiate another browser instance. The browser instance is created when you do `new ChromeDriver()` so you will want that inside the `for` loop. Something like this should work.

```
class callingfunction
{
    public static IWebDriver driver = null;

    public void function1()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
           driver = new ChromeDriver(Cpath); // launch browser
           driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.aaa.org");
           driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.aaa.org/contactus");
           driver.FindElement(By.Name("contact")).SendKeys(contact);
           driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.aaa.org/aboutus");
           //Code logic 

           driver.Close(); // close browser
        }
        driver.Quit(); // close browser driver
    }
}
```

Is there some reason you need to close the browser between runs? You can't just reuse the existing browser instance? Your test will run much faster... but sometimes there is a need to close it. Only you would know...

Comment: Actually during the iteration, browser open the two tabs and every time when next iteration starts, it opens the another 2 tab. So I want to close the tabs after each iteration because it create an application slow. Can you please suggest what can be the best option.

Comment: I don't see any code in your sample that would open multiple tabs. I would start by determining what code is opening the different tabs and fix that. It doesn't sound like you need more than one tab open and it can be reused throughout the test.

Comment: Let me try your suggestion.